# Reference for Existence and uniqueness of an Integro-Differential Equation

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, differential-equations, integral-operators, existence-theorems

I have an Integro-Differential Equation (IDE) of the following form:
$$
x'(t) = f(t,x(t)) + \int_0^t K(t-s, x(s), x(t)) ds,
$$
I have found [this classical reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2884490000), but the IDEs considered therein have $K$ as a function of $(t,s,x(s))$, whilst for me it is essential to also consider the dependence on $x(t)$. Here the domain of $x$ is a function from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ and $K$ are both smooth functions.

I am simply looking for criteria under which the IDE has a (unique) solution.

Comment: Are you just asking for a good reference or you have a real trouble establishing some desired solvability properties in your particular setting?

Comment: just a reference

Comment: I have been able to show that if, as a boundary condition, we have $x_1(0) \leq x_2(0)$ that the associated solutions to the IDE satisfy $x_1(s) \leq x_2(s)$ for all $s$.